# 2 docker containers (Django & React), isomorphic-fetch and a login request

Tags: django, reactjs, docker, django-rest-framework, isomorphic-fetch-api

My setup is running on Docker with a frontend (React) as well as a backend (Django) container.

I'm using the login-form component of the drf-react-app below in another project and am clueless as to how the api fetch request in the loginUser action creator  (src/actions/user.js) knows which URL it is supposed to use..?

```
user.js:22 POST http://localhost:3000/api/obtain-auth-token/ 404 (Not Found)
```

I want it to send the request to the server at port 8000. I took the code from this drf-react boilerplate: https://github.com/moritz91/drf-react-login

```
export function loginUser(username, password) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {

        const payload = {username, password};

        dispatch({type: LOGIN_USER_REQUEST, payload});

        return fetch(`/api/obtain-auth-token/`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(payload)
        })
        .then(handleResponse(dispatch, LOGIN_USER_RESPONSE))
        .then((json) => {
            saveUser(json);
            return json;
        })
        .catch(handleError(dispatch, LOGIN_USER_RESPONSE))
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `package.json` you have a `proxy` property set to `"http://backend:8000"`. The proxy is used to redirect requests to a given url when you make a request **against your local server** `http://localhost:3000`. So if that's not working then you might be missing a step that enables the proxy.

Comment: That's it..! It was working the first time I restarted the containers, but now it's raising the old error again. The only difference to the github drf-react app is that I'm using webpack-dev-server. When I set the proxy property on the def-server settings in the webpack-config.js I get an ECONNREFUSED error. I would prefer to use the proxy as shown in the github example. Any idea what I'm missing to enable the proxy?